# 10% accuracy during training, however the prediction using same model on train data gives only 3.5% accuracy

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, computer-vision

I'm training the VGG16 block5 with code below over 100 iterations/epochs, adding up two dense and dropout layer after the output of block5.

```
seq = Sequential()
vgg_base = VGG16(weights='imagenet', input_shape=(224, 224, 3),include_top=False, pooling='avg')
seq.add(vgg_base)


for layer in vgg_base.layers:
    layer.trainable = False
for layer in vgg_base.layers[:14]:
    layer.trainable = False
for layer in vgg_base.layers[15:]:
    layer.trainable = True
    
regularizer = tf.keras.regularizers.l2(1e-2)

for layer in vgg_base.layers[15:]:
    for attr in ['kernel_regularizer']:
        if hasattr(layer, attr):
          setattr(layer, attr, regularizer)

vgg_base.summary()
#seq.add(Flatten())

input_a = Input(shape=(224, 224, 3))

out_a = seq(input_a)

hidden1 = Dense(128, activation='relu', name='dense_1', kernel_regularizer=tf.keras.regularizers.l2(0.001),
                              activity_regularizer=tf.keras.regularizers.l2(0.001))(out_a)
hidden_drp1 = Dropout(0.5)(hidden1)
hidden2 = Dense(32, activation='relu', name='dense_2',kernel_regularizer=tf.keras.regularizers.l2(0.001),
                              activity_regularizer=tf.keras.regularizers.l2(0.001))(hidden_drp1)
hidden_drp2 = Dropout(0.2)(hidden2)
out = Dense(1, activation='sigmoid', name='dense_3')(hidden_drp2)

model = Model(input_a, out)
```

Training settings:

```
if os.path.exists(filepath):
     print('weights found... loading...')
     model.load_weights(filepath)

train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1.0/255)
                                   #,validation_split=0.4)
#        validation_split=0.3) # set validation split

train_path = 'C:/fromtrainv4/'

train_set = train_datagen.flow_from_directory(
    train_path,
    target_size=(224,224),
    shuffle=True,
    color_mode='rgb',
    batch_size=100,
    class_mode='binary')
optim = Adam(lr=0.001)
loss = 'binary_crossentropy'
metrics = ['binary_accuracy', 'acc']

model.compile(loss=loss,
              optimizer=optim,
              metrics=metrics)

checkpoint = ModelCheckpoint(filepath,
                             monitor='loss',
                             verbose=1,
                             save_weights_only=False,
                             save_best_only=True,
                             mode='min')

my_callback = [tf.keras.callbacks.EarlyStopping(monitor='loss', patience=10),
               checkpoint,tf.keras.callbacks.TensorBoard(log_dir='C:\\traning_logs\\')]
step_size_train = train_set.n//train_set.batch_size
history = model.fit_generator(train_set,
                             steps_per_epoch=step_size_train,
                             shuffle=False,
                             epochs=100,
                             callbacks=my_callback,
                             class_weight='balanced')
```

I have made sure that the data has same scaling as image_generator and everything else.
I load the model using code below:

```
from tensorflow.keras.models import load_model
model = load_model('C:/models/model.h5')
```

System Specs:

```
Processor: Intell Xeon
Ram: 16GB
GPU: NVIDIA RTX 2080 Super
Memory: M2. 256GB

Interpreter: Spyder Python 3.7.1
tensorflow version: 1.14.0
keras version: 2.3.1
```

Can someone guide me what I might be doing wrong. Please let me know if more information regarding this is required.

Answer (score 0):

I would guess that your model is doing what is called "overfitting".

In short, by doing 100 train iterations of the same dataset, it kind of memorized by heart your train dataset and thus have a good result when tested on it. However it doesn't yet find a general answer to your problem which lead to lower results when testing with a new dataset with different inputs.

Comment: i think the problem is about weird results in training data after training. So overfitting is ruled out for his problem

Comment: @Kasonnara overfitting should not be the case since the result doesn't appear to be the same on training set at the time of testing.

Comment: @drops, Checked:
1.  The image to be of same type
2. Normalized as at the time of training
3. setup of images (since I'm combining images for training and for testing)
4. The data to be same for training and testing the training set.

is there something else I should check.

Comment: I mistakenly wrote 10% its actually 100% this training accuracy. Is there a way I can edit this question?